# invalid format exception while using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to insert data of excel file in database using POI api, but when i upload excel file with .xlsx extension it is giving this exception " org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]". Previously I have tried to do same and it was working fine, but when I edited excel file and save it to new file with .xlsx (automatic filename extension) it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

When your file is saved with .xls file extension you can use the Workbook class by using HSSFWorkbook instance, but when using .xlsx you can use Workbook class by using XSSFWorkbook instance as :

```
Workbook w = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

(it worked for me for .xlsx extension files)

Can you share your code please...